# How to resize autocomplete window in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, text-editor

I'm using Sublime text 2 as text editor for HTML and JavaScript and I have a small problem. I'm using autocomplete but some of the function's names are so long that I can see only first 5 or 6 symbols of it. Is anybody knows how can I resize the autocomplete window? Thanks again.

Comment: SynWrite app has autocomplete window size changable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible in ST2. It might not be in ST3 either, but at least the autocomplete pop-up adapts its size to the content. Should you consider an update, make sure to have a look at the [Can I switch to Sublime Text 3](http://www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com/) website first.

Comment: +1 for that website, I hadn't come across it before.